# What is the proper way to avoid Retain Cycle while using blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block, weak

What is the proper way to add objects in NSMutableArray which is strongly defined by property.

```
[tapBlockView setTapBlock:^(UIImage* image) {
   [self.myImageArray addObject:image]; // self retain cycle
}
```

If I will create weak reference something like

```
__weak NSMutableArray *array = self.myImageArray;
[tapBlockView setTapBlock:^(UIImage* image) {
    [array addObject:image]; // If I will do this then how will I update original Array ?
}
```

I have also tried

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[tapBlockView setTapBlock:^(UIImage* image) {
    [weakSelf storeImageInaNewMethod:image]; // Calling SToreImageInaNewMethod
}
```

and

```
-(void)storeImageInaNewMethod:(UIImage*)image {
   [self.myImageArray addObject:image]; // This again retaining cycle
}
```

What is the proper way to update original object defined by property ?

Comment: Blocks are like function pointers.Can't you just set the block to nil when you don't need it anymore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a combination of the 2nd and 3rd.

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[tapBlockView setTapBlock:^(UIImage* image) {
    [weakSelf.myImageArray addObject:image];
}
```

Comment: Note this is only valid if you use weakSelf on the first line of the block, if you do anything else first then you need Kaan's answer.

Answer (score 15):

After maddy's answer - this is from 2012 WWDC lecture on GCD and asynchronous programming:

```
__weak MyClass *weakSelf = self;

[tapBlockView setTapBlock:^(UIImage* image) {
    __strong MyClass *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if(strongSelf) {
        [strongSelf.myImageArray addObject:image];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I am not getting why you are changing into __strong again ? I guess only this code is sufficient ? [weakSelf.myImageArray addObject:image];

Comment: The reason for the cast back to `__strong` is to guarantee that if `weakSelf` is still alive when the first line of the block is executed, it will continue to live for the remainder of the execution of the block.

Comment: If you turned on warnings then you would see why the __strong is needed: A weak variable can disappear at any point, including in the middle of the call weakSelf.myImageArray which surely will cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you only need to reference an array which is referenced by `self`, so:

```
NSMutableArray *array = self.myImageArray;
[tapBlockView setTapBlock:^(UIImage* image)
                          {
                             [array addObject:image]; // No cycle
                          }];
```

Works fine *provided* that `self.myImageArray` does not return different array references at different times. There is no cycle: the current object references the array and the block, and in turn the block references the array.

If `self.myImageArray` does return different array references as different times then use a weak reference to `self`, your case 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your second and third ones appear correct. The second one works because you did not create a copy of the array, so that still points to the original one. The third one works because the reference to self is weak.

Comment: The 2nd one only works if `self.myImageArray` returns a direct reference to the ivar. That may not be a safe assumption.