# Block retain on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, retain

Could someone help me understand which approach is 'best' with regard to avoiding a block retain cycle..

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
weakSelf.myProperty = @"something";
```

vs

```
self->myProperty = @"something";
```

The later is being recommended by xCode 5.1 and the former is what seems to be historically recommended.

Thanks

Comment: `self->myProperty` will also retain `self`.

Comment: here `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self; weakSelf = @"something";` you are erasing `weakSelf = self` with `@"something"`

Comment: @Avt I fixed the typo.

Comment: I remember that in one of past WWDCs they said using __weak and __strong references is OK for avoiding retain cycles. So before block you declare your reference as __weak id this = self; and inside block __strong UIViewController *strongThis = this;. Check @Kaan Dedeoglu answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257356/what-is-the-proper-way-to-avoid-retain-cycle-while-using-blocks

Comment: What do you mean by *"the latter being recommended by Xcode 5.1"*? Do you have any reference?

Comment: A 'Semantic Issue' warning generated by Xcode. The issue is described as "Block implicitly retains self". The 'fix-it' pop generated by Xcode suggests 'Insert self->'

Comment: Rob, thanks. I'd accept your explanation as the answer if it wasn't a comment. I guess my main source of confusion was down to not being familiar with the -> syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time Apple really talks about `self->_ivar` syntax is when they're observing out that a reference to some instance variable, `_ivar`, alone, is really equivalent to `self->_ivar`, and thus referring to `_ivar` within a block will implicitly retain `self`. But they're not really recommending you use `self->_ivar`, just pointing out the issue associated with using instance variables within blocks, that they entail implicit references to `self`.

You said:

> A 'Semantic Issue' warning generated by Xcode. The issue is described as "Block implicitly retains self". The 'fix-it' pop generated by Xcode suggests 'Insert self->'

I can only guess that the suggestion by Xcode is to ensure that implicit references to `self` are replaced with explicit references, and thus, when you employ the `weakSelf` pattern, you'll be able to see each reference to `self` that needs replacing. Clearly, it would be hard for Xcode to know the name of your `__weak` rendition of `self`, so it's hard for it to suggest that, but their proposed edit does help avoid missing some implicit reference to `self`.

By the way, once you convert those ivar references, e.g. `_ivar`, with `self->_ivar`, it will be tempting to then simply go through the code in the block, replacing the references to `self` with your new `weakSelf` variable. But be careful: The construct `weakSelf->_ivar` is problematic because if `weakSelf` is `nil`, that will generate a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at runtime. If this ivar is simply backing some property, then use the property (e.g. `weakSelf.property`). Property accessor methods correctly handle `nil` pointers (doing nothing), but dereferencing an ivar of a `nil` pointer will generate the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Ideally in that scenario, just use the property accessor method instead and you're done. But, if there is no property associated with this `_ivar`, then you have to employ the pattern joking referred to as the "`weakSelf`/`strongSelf` dance". So, let's assume you had code that looked like:

```
someBlockVariable = ^{
    // do something

    // now try to set an ivar

    _ivar = ...;
};
```

Doing that `_ivar` to `self->_ivar` change that Xcode suggests, and then substituting `weakSelf`, you'd end up with:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

someBlockVariable = ^{
    // do something

    // now try to set an ivar

    weakSelf->_ivar = ...;
};
```

But that's bad (for the reasons I describe above). In fact, the compiler will even warn you that you cannot dereference a weak pointer. So what you'd want to do is:

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

someBlockVariable = ^{
    // do something

    // now try to set an ivar

    typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;

    if (strongSelf) {
        strongSelf->_ivar = ...;
    }
};
```

And don't worry about the reference to `typeof(self)` in the block, as that will not retain `self`.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the time you took to explain

Answer (score 0):

This seems very confused. Or maybe you saw an example and removed too much code, so that it doesn't make sense anymore.

A "weak" object pointer doesn't keep a retain count on the object and becomes nil whenever the object is deallocated, which happens when the object loses its last retain count.

So whenever you see a "weak" object pointer, that pointer might be nil or change to nil soon. As a consequence, code like

```
[weakself method1];
[weakself method2];
[weakself method3];
```

should be avoided, because weakself might become nil after the first or second call, and calling only one or two methods could lead to wrong results. Instead you write

```
strongself = weakself;
[strongself method1];
[strongself method2];
[strongself method3];
```

strong self might be nil or not, but because it is a strong object pointer, it will hold a reference to the object (if it isn't nil), so all three methods will be called or none of them.

```
weakself->myproperty = @"Something";
```

is highly dangerous - it will crash if weakself is nil. So will

```
strongself = weakself;
strongself->myproperty = @"Something";
```

It is rarely correct to assign directly to instance variables, except inside the implementation of the class.

Minor addition: It's "former" and "latter", not "later". That's a case where a spelling mistake is very confusing, so you should try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

1.used second one when you sure your code does not create any retain cycle.

2.now come to your problem

block are closures , they strongly refer to any object which it contain  including self. so
if self does not strongly refer block you can use your second syntax inside the block because retain  cycle will not be generated. BUT if your self is also refer the same block strongly , then it will generate a retain cycle.

so you have to use your first syntax and you can later on strongify it inside the block according to your use.