# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using dispatch_block_t

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a game menu, intro scene and game itself. If player is dead I would like to show game menu again. When game starts menu shows up. Pressing new game shows intro scene as it should. After some time of animation self.sceneEndCallback() is triggered and game scene is shown. When player is dead self.gameEndCallback() crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

**GameViewController.m**

```
        __weak GameViewController *weakSelf = self;
        IntroScene *introScene = [IntroScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"IntroScene"];
        introScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [skView presentScene:introScene];
        introScene.sceneEndCallback = ^{
            GameScene *scene = [GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:@"GameScene"];
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
            SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:2];
            [skView presentScene:scene transition:transition];
            scene.gameEndCallback = ^{
                [weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            };

        };
```

inside **GameScene.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) dispatch_block_t gameEndCallback;
```

Comment: 1. Please, provide crash log. 2. Are you checking that `gameEndCallback` is not `NULL` before invoking it?

Comment: Not directly related to your crash, but you should also re-grab a strong reference to self and check for nil before referencing it rather than directly referencing weakSelf like you're doing here.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257356/what-is-the-proper-way-to-avoid-retain-cycle-while-using-blocks/13257892#13257892

Comment: @BorisVerebsky you're right. gameEndCallback is NULL. But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is anything actually calling the `introScene.sceneEndCallback`?  Because, without that, `scene.gameEndCallback` will be NULL and attempting to call it will crash with BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Well yes, because GameScene is presented after IntroScene.

Comment: Then make sure it is being called on the right instance.

Comment: What do you mean? It's being called on the right instance, but somehow gameEndCallback is NULL...

Comment: Actually, I just had to assign GameEndCallback before transitioning to scene. Switching those two lines together made it work. :)